# How to find Font version from OTF,TTF file

Tags: fonts, terminal, version

I am using custom fonts in otf and ttf formats. I don't how to find the version of the font.

Is there any way to find the version of oft and ttf fonts using a Mac?

Comment: Could you update your question to reflect whether you are trying to determine this programatically? Also by "version" do you mean "whether it is OTF or TTF"?

Answer (score 8):

On Linux we can use the `fc-query` tool to extract the `fontversion` information:

```
fc-query -f '%{fontversion}\n' /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf | perl -E 'printf "%.3f\n", <>/65536.0'
2.350
```

Example on Mac (with `fontconfig` installed via homebrew):

```
fc-query -f '%{fontversion}\n' /System/Library/Fonts/Apple\ Symbols.ttf | perl -E 'printf "%.3f\n", <>/65536.0'
5.000
```

Comment: this command also works on Mac

Answer (score 1):

By right click the otf,ttf and selecting "Get info" displays many information along with Font version in Mac